# Why am not able to access column in my data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I am new to R and I need some help on why I am not able to access my data frame properly

```
> str(new_df)
List of 1    <~~~~  SEE THIS LINE  (note to OP, sorry for commenting on the question - RS)
 $ :'data.frame':   16 obs. of  2 variables:
  ..$ x: num [1:16] 2002 2003 2004 2005 2006 ...
  ..$ y: num [1:16] 457320 431640 412090 389090 396020 ...
> new_df$x
NULL
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `is(new_df)` and you will see it is a list of a data.frame. In which case you would have to use `new_df[[1]]` to access the first element of the list which is the data.frame.